# Can anyone explain to me this piece of code? I am new to C

Tags: c, string, reverse

I am trying to learn C, so I went to try out some of the coderbyte challenges in C, one of which is to reverse a string. After gettung multiple compilation errors due to syntax I tried looking for examples and encountered this one on http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-reverse-string

```
#include<stdio.h>

int string_length(char*);
void reverse(char*);

main() 
{
  char string[100];

  printf("Enter a string\n");
  gets(string);

  reverse(string);

  printf("Reverse of entered string is \"%s\".\n", string);

  return 0;
```

}

```
   void reverse(char *string) 
   {
      int length, c;
      char *begin, *end, temp;

      length = string_length(string);
      begin  = string;
      end    = string;

      for (c = 0; c < length - 1; c++)
         end++;

      for (c = 0; c < length/2; c++)
      {        
         temp   = *end;
         *end   = *begin;
         *begin = temp;

          begin++;
          end--;
      }
   }

   int string_length(char *pointer)
   {
      int c = 0;

    while( *(pointer + c) != '\0' )//I DON'T UNDERSTAND THIS PART!!!!!
      c++;

    return c;
}
```

c is not even a char, so why would you add it? Or is pointer some sort of index considering the context of the while loop?

Comment: `gets(string);` means your are learning from old text/instructor as `gets()` has been dropped from C since C11..

Comment: As mentioned by @chux gets() is deprecated. You should use fgets(), which also prevents buffer overflow

Comment: Re:"//I don't understand this part:" `pointer` is the address of the first element of `string`. Since a string consists of characters, size of a character is `1` and a string is terminated by `\0` (null character), the counter advances until it reaches `\0` and returns last value. Please take the advice against using `gets()` _very_ seriously.

Comment: Using a variable `c` as an index into a string probably isn't the best practice for clarity, but there's nothing unusual about it.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator here does not mean string concatenation; it means pointer arithmetic.  `pointer` is a pointer to a `char`, and `c` is an `int`, so `pointer + c` results in a pointer to a `char` that is `c` `char`s further forward in memory.  For example, if you have an array `{'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'}` and `pointer` pointed at the `'j'`, and `c` was 2, then `pointer + c` would point at the `'l'`.  If you advance a pointer like this then deference it, that acts the same as the array indexing syntax: `pointer[c]`.  The loop is therefore equivalent to:

```
while( pointer[c] != '\0' )
  c++;
```

The effect of adding a pointer to an integer (or vice-versa) scales according to the size of what the pointer is (supposedly) pointing to, so you don't need to account for different sizes of objects.  `foo + 5`, if `foo` is a pointer, will go 5 objects further forward in memory, whatever size object `foo` points to (assuming that `foo` is pointing at the type it is declared to point to).

Answer (score 2):

Here you can talk about pointer arithmetic.

There is an important concept :

- Addition a integer to a pointer will **move the pointer** forward. The number that you are adding will be **multiplied** by the **size of type** that the pointer is pointing to.

Example :

An int is coded on 4 bytes, so when we increment the pointer by 1, we have to multiply by 4 to obtain what really happen in regular arithmetic.

```
int a[3] = {1, 3, 6};

printf("%d\n", *(a + 1)); // print 3, look 4 bytes ahead

printf("%d \n", *(a + 2)); //print 6, look 8 bytes ahead
```

In your case :

A char is coded on 1 byte so

```
*(pointer + c) with c == 3
```

will evaluate to a memory address of 3 bytes (3 chars) ahead.

So the code :

```
while( *(pointer + c) != '\0' )
  c++;
```

will evaluate the value of your pointer at a specific memory address. If the character is equal to the **null-character**, we have reached the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `*(pointer + c)` is equivalent to `pointer[c]`.
`c` is being used as an index.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /* reverse: Reverses the string pointed to by `string` */
   void reverse(char *string) 
   {
      int length, c;
      char *begin, *end, temp;

      /* compute length of string, initialize pointers */
      length = string_length(string);
      begin  = string;  /* points to the beginning of string */
      end    = string;  /* will later point to the end of string */

      /* make end point to the end */
      for (c = 0; c < length - 1; c++)
         end++;

      /* walk through half of the string */
      for (c = 0; c < length/2; c++)
      {        
         /* swap the begin and end pointers */
         temp   = *end;
         *end   = *begin;
         *begin = temp;

          /* advance pointers */
          begin++;
          end--;
      }
   }

/* computes length of pointer */
int string_length(char *pointer)
{
    int c = 0;

    /* while we walk `pointer` and we don't see the null terminator */
    while( *(pointer + c) != '\0' )//I DON'T UNDERSTAND THIS PART!!!!!
        c++; /* advance position, c */

    /* return the length */
    return c;
}
```

The `string_length` function can be rewritten as

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; *str; ++i)
        ;

    return i;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand if the string is : abcd
the result would be : dcba
if the input is : HELLO-WORLD
the output would be :  DLROW-OLLEH

Comment: reverse function changes the string .. how ? well it's goes from 2 to lengh/2, switch end & begin in each iteration, ofc begin++ & end-- to not make infinite loop